# why am I unable to dual boot windows 11 with ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: dual-boot

I was unable to install ubuntu 20.04 while dual booting and unable to detect the disks. can anyone please help.

Comment: try disabling Intel RST from BIOS (**this might potentially format your disk**, especially if your disks are using RAID)

Comment: How new is system? Often you need a Linux distribution that is 6 mo to a year newer than hardware to have all the latest kernel & drivers. Windows 11 systems are typically only on very new systems. Have you tried latest 22.04 or next months 24.04?